# How to do a JSON.stringify in a Firebase push?

Tags: json, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to push to Firebase database.
I can't get to be able to use the `JSON.stringify` function to work within a Firebase `push({})` method.

```
push(path:string, body){
     this.api_url = this.af.database.object(`${path}`);
     return this.api_url.set({ JSON.stringify(body) });
  }
```

I get the following error when I try the above:

```
':' expected.)
    at _checkDiagnostics (D:\angular2\myapp\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:116:15)...
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Why does your title mention `push`? Your code calls `set`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call `JSON.stringify`, just use:

```ts
this.api_url.set(body);
```

Or, if you really do want to store a JSON string in Firebase (which seems unlikely), you should use:

```ts
this.api_url.set(JSON.stringify(body));
```

You question mentions both `push` and `set`. This answer uses `set`, but also applies to `push`.